# On Google analytics, page view stay to 1 for ads campaign, but work perfectly for natural search on a view.js SPA using tag manager

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We set a Google tag manager on our SPA website (with view.js and nuxe for server side rendering).
We add google analytics on tag manager which works perfectly for direct and natural traffic.
Enhance Ecommerce works well too.

We connected Google ads to Google analytics in order to see our ads campaigns.
Now we see our ads campaigns on Google analytics, but the bounce rate stay to 100% and the page view stay to 1 for around 95% of our campaigns.

Hotjar shows us many visits from ads campaigns with more than 1 page view, which let us think that there is a problem with ads campaign on Google analytics.

Using chrome extension "Google tag assistant" we saw google tagmanager duplication when we navigate on different page. But with F12 on Chrome I see only 1 tagmanager and it seems not be refresh when I navigate.

On tagmanager the analytics page view is triggered on "all page" for the page open and "history change" for the navigation.

The error appears when I click on a ads campaign on Google. But if I manually open the same page adding a gclid params it seems to work fine on Google analytics.

Errors appear on https://www.pandacola.com/

Can you help us, thank you